# Can I send data from the database to my Android app using FCM cloud

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have an app that allow users to write posts and comment on posts . I want to use firebase cloud FCM to send the post writer notification when his post has a new comment . I will use FCM cloud to show the user writer the notification. But after that I need when the user clicks on this notification an activity opens with the post and comments appears in it . To do that I need to send to the user the post child from the database to be opened when the notification clicked. My problem is that I don't know if it's possible to send the data from the database or not ? and if it can be done I need to know how ?

Comment: you can send data in your FCM message BUT a better implementation would be to when the activity loads just have the app get any new messages from your server

Comment: as @tyczj said you can do both. Doing your approach will work but FCM has payload limit of 4KB, if you are sending couple of IDs than fine.

Comment: @Zaki how can I send the data

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using cloud functions to send notifications to the user's device using tokens.
You can send data to the recipient activity like below. Here, you need to send your postID. 
Now your payload will look something like this:

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
        title: you_notification_title,
        body: text,
        icon : "ic_notification_small",
        sound : "default",
        click_action: "NEW_MESSAGE",
        "content_available": "true",
        badge : "1"
    }, 
       data: {
            postID: "your_postID",
        }
    };
```

Here `click_action` is the key. Activity which is marked with "NEW_MESSAGE" in Android Manifest.xml will be launched when user click the notification. So in order to an activity be launched when the notification is clicked, it should be defined in manifest like below:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Your_Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="NEW_MESSAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now, when your users click the notification, they will be taken to `Your_Activity`.

In your `Your_Activity`, you can get the data from the notification like this:

```
String postID= remoteMessage.getData().get(“postID”);
```

Using this postID, you need to fetch the corresponding data for that post from firebase.

Comment: I need to know how to send the post id to the NEW_MESSAGE activity it's stored with the new comment in the database if you told me how to send this id from the comment child to the NEW_MESSAGE activity I will accept your answer

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I will try to do this now

Comment: @KarthicSrinivasan you haven't explain how to get the post id

Comment: Please check the last part of my answer. You can get postID in your landing activity like this: String postID= remoteMessage.getData().get(“postID”)

Comment: @KarthicSrinivasan I mean that you haven't explain what is remoteMessage and how to use it

Comment: Data sent through FCM will be received by onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage) in the landing activity. You can use RemoteMessage object to get the data parceled in the notification bundle. For more detailed explanations, check out official documentation of RemoteMessage here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage